# Rails database.yml disappear in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, github

I have a Rails 3.2.x app which I recently removed database.yml out of version control in `git` bit adding `/config/database.yml` to `.gitignore` in my app directory and did a `git rm --cached config/database.yml` in my app directory.  I have the `database.yml` file on my production and staging server under `app/shared/config/database.yml` and I symlink to it via my `Capistrano` `deploy.rb` file.

In my dev environment on my master branch I recreated the `database.yml` file and I can continue development, but every so often the file disappears from the directory entirely and I have to recreate it.  Note, I have `Sublime Text 2` open usually with `database.yml` being one of the files that I have open most of the time.

Things will run fine for a while but all of a sudden the file will disappear from the master branch `config` directory on my local disk and I have to recreate it.

What could be causing this file to disappear randomly?  `git` ignores it and I just use a local copy in my master branch.  Could this be from switching branches?  Or because my text editor has it open?

It's not a huge deal because I have a backup copy and I can just drop in, but this only started since I pulled it out of version control/`git`.

Any thoughts on why this is happening?  There are times when I need to demo the app and don't want to have any "hiccups".

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I don't want to have to commit `database.yml` back to version control, that's for sure but this problem is perplexing as to why it disappears randomly.

Comment: Note, I can make the file disappear when switching branches (which the other branch has `config/database.yml` in it.  When I switch back to `master` the `config/database.yml` is gone and I have to recreate it.  But sometimes the file will just disappear on its own.

Comment: do you see the config/database.yml in your version control in any branch. If so it might be the case that you took the pull and database.yml comes with it?

Comment: @Hemali yes it's in one of my other feature branches.  I haven't pulled but I did `git rm --cached config/database.yml` in the master branch but not the other branches.  Should I do it in other branches and commit?

Comment: did you figure this out????? it drives me CRAZY